# How to fix this circular import error in Python

Tags: python, circular-dependency

I have build a Python wrapper for a REST API that currently returns the raw JSON data. My next step is to convert the JSON data into Python objects. For this reason, I've made a Resource class with all the necessary methods to convert a dict into the relevant object.

How do I fix this circular import error?
I have thought of removing the `periods` field from the Calendar class, but them I'm limiting the functionality of the API.

```py
# test.py
from my_project.endpoints import Calendars
from my_project.resources import Calendar

calendars = Calendars(username, password).list()
calendars = [Calendar(**calendar) for calendar in calendars]

# ImportError: cannot import name 'Calendar' from partially initialized module 'my_project.model.resources.calendar' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

```py
# my_project/client.py
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields

@dataclass
class Resource:
    def __post_init__(self, *_):
        for f in fields(self):
            value = getattr(self, f.name)
            if f.type is list and value is not None:
                astype = f.metadata.get("type", str)
                setattr(self, f.name, [self.__cast(v, astype) for v in value])
            else:
                setattr(self, f.name, self.__cast(value, f.type))

    @classmethod
    def __cast(cls, value, astype):
        if value is None:
            return None
        if astype is datetime:
            return datetime.fromisoformat(value)
        elif astype is date:
            return datetime.fromisoformat(value).date()
        elif astype == cls.__name__:
            key = cls._key()
            return cls(**{key: value})
        elif issubclass(astype, Resource) and isinstance(value, dict):
            return astype(**value)
        elif issubclass(astype, Resource) and isinstance(value, (str, int)):
            return astype(**{astype._key(): value})
        else:
            return astype(value)

    @classmethod
    def _key(cls) -> tuple:
        for f in fields(cls):
            if f.metadata.get("key"):
                return f.name
```

```py
# my_project/resources.py
from my_project.model.resources.calendar import Calendar
from my_project.model.resources.period import Period
from my_project.model.resources.periodType import PeriodType

__all__ = ["Calendar", "Period", "PeriodType"]
```

```py
# my_project/model/resources/calender.py
from my_project.model.resources.period import Period

@dataclass
class Calendar(Resource):
    calenderSeq: str = field(default=None)
    name: str = field(default=None)
    description: str = field(default=None)
    periods: list = field(default=None, metadata={"type": Period})
```

```py
# my_project/model/resources/period.py
from my_project.model.resources.calendar import Calendar
from my_project.model.resources.periodType import PeriodType

@dataclass
class Period(Resource):
    periodSeq: str = field(default=None)
    name: str = field(default=None)
    description: str = field(default=None)
    periodType: PeriodType = field(default=None)
    calendar: Calendar = field(default=None)
```

**Edit**
As per the comment of Davis (thanks for the suggestion), I tried combining all the files into a single resources.py. Despite the `from __future__ import annotations`, still got the error `NameError: name 'Period' is not defined`.

```py
# my_project/resources.py
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import InitVar, dataclass, field
from datetime import date, datetime

from sapcommissions import Resource


@dataclass
class Calendar(Resource):
    calenderSeq: str = field(default=None)
    name: str = field(default=None)
    description: str = field(default=None)
    periods: list = field(default=None, metadata={"type": Period}) # error here


@dataclass
class Period(Resource):
    periodSeq: str = field(default=None)
    name: str = field(default=None)
    description: str = field(default=None)
    periodType: PeriodType = field(default=None)
    calendar: Calendar = field(default=None)


@dataclass
class PeriodType(Resource):
    periodTypeSeq: str = field(default=None)
    name: str = field(default=None)
    description: str = field(default=None)
    level: int = field(default=None)
```

Comment: Is “don’t put every class in its own file like it’s Java” an acceptable answer?

Comment: perhaps it is, but then I still have the issue of the order of the classes. I can't put Calendar above Period because Period is referenced in the Calendar class, and visa versa.

Comment: Pre-declare `Period = 'Period'` before the `Calendar` class definition.

Comment: Thanks @PeterWood , I tried your solution. Unfortunately the error now changed to `TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class` (in the `__cast` function) because `Period` is now effectively an instance of str, not a subclass of anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need `from __future__ import annotations` to postpone evaluation of annotations and to support forward references in annotations.

But this makes field's type a string rather than a type in dataclass. That's `dataclasses.Field.type` becomes name of it's type instead of the type itself.

To fix this, we have to `eval` the field's type to get it's type.

And because `eval` requires access to objects which it evaluates and also to make things simpler, I've integrated everything into a single module.

I check if a field's type is `str` in `__post_init__` then only `eval` it to avoid `eval`ing a type if future versions of Python changes behavior. This is for Python 3.8.

```
from __future__ import annotations
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields, field
from datetime import datetime, date


@dataclass
class Resource:
    def __post_init__(self, *_):
        for f in fields(self):
            value = getattr(self, f.name)
            field_type = f.type
            if isinstance(f.type, str):
                field_type = eval(f.type)
            # if f.type is list and value is not None:
            if field_type is list and value is not None:
                astype = f.metadata.get("type", str)
                setattr(self, f.name, [self.__cast(v, astype) for v in value])
            else:
                setattr(self, f.name, self.__cast(value, field_type))
                # setattr(self, f.name, self.__cast(value, f.type))

    @classmethod
    def __cast(cls, value, astype):
        if value is None:
            return None
        if astype is datetime:
            return datetime.fromisoformat(value)
        elif astype is date:
            return datetime.fromisoformat(value).date()
        elif astype == cls.__name__:
            key = cls._key()
            return cls(**{key: value})
        elif issubclass(astype, Resource) and isinstance(value, dict):
            return astype(**value)
        elif issubclass(astype, Resource) and isinstance(value, (str, int)):
            return astype(**{astype._key(): value})
        else:
            return astype(value)

    @classmethod
    def _key(cls) -> tuple:
        for f in fields(cls):
            if f.metadata.get("key"):
                return f.name


@dataclass
class Period(Resource):
    periodSeq: str = field(default=None)
    name: str = field(default=None)
    description: str = field(default=None)
    periodType: PeriodType = field(default=None)
    calendar: Calendar = field(default=None)


@dataclass
class Calendar(Resource):
    calenderSeq: str = field(default=None)
    name: str = field(default=None)
    description: str = field(default=None)
    periods: list = field(default=None, metadata={"type": Period})  # error here


@dataclass
class PeriodType(Resource):
    periodTypeSeq: str = field(default=None)
    name: str = field(default=None)
    description: str = field(default=None)
    level: int = field(default=None)
```

Comment: Thank you Nizam. The `__cast` method will not be able to recognize the `Calendar` class, it only sees the string `"Calendar"` and is therefor unable to convert the data into the object.

Comment: What error do you get? What Python version do you run?

Comment: The error is
`elif issubclass(astype, Resource) and isinstance(value, dict): TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class` and I'm working with Python 3.9.12

Comment: The same behaviour is forces when you `from __future__ import annotations`. Then `str` also becomes `"str"`, as discussed in this article https://bugs.python.org/issue39442

Comment: did you try removing `from __future__ import annotations`?

Comment: Yes, I just meant to say that it casues the same behaviour. I don't have `from __future__ import annotations` in the file

Comment: Updated to fix TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class